# AVAudioPlayerNode - Mix between schedule buffers and segments

Tags: ios, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I'm writing an application where I should play parts of audio files. Each audio file contains audio data for a separate track.
These parts are sections with a begin time and a end time, and I'm trying to play those parts in the order I choose.

So for example, imagine I have 4 sections :

A - B - C - D

and I activate B and D, I want to play, B, then D, then B again, then D, etc..

To make smooth 'jumps" in playback I think it's important to fade in/out start/end sections buffers.

So, I have a basic `AVAudioEngine` setup, with `AVAudioPlayerNode`, and a mixer.
For each audio section, I cache some information :

- a buffer for the first samples in the section (which I fade in manually)
- a tuple for the `AVAudioFramePosition`, and `AVAudioFrameCount` of a middle segment
- a buffer for the end samples in the audio section (which I fade out manually)

now, when I schedule a section for playing, I say the `AVAudioPlayerNode` :

- schedule the start buffer (`scheduleBuffer(_:completionHandler:)` no option)
- schedule the middle segment (`scheduleSegment(_:startingFrame:frameCount:at:completionHandler:)`)
- finally schedule the end buffer (`scheduleBuffer(_:completionHandler:)` no option)

all at "time" `nil`.

The problem here is I can hear clic, and crappy sounds at audio sections boundaries and I can't see where I'm doing wrong.
My first idea was the fades I do manually (basically multiplying sample values by a volume factor), but same result without doing that.
I thought I didn't schedule in time, but scheduling sections in advance, A - B - C for example beforehand has the same result.
I then tried different frame position computations, with audio format settings, same result.

So I'm out of ideas here, and perhaps I didn't get the schedule mechanism right.

Can anyone confirm I can mix scheduling buffers and segments in `AVAudioPlayerNode` ? or should I schedule only buffers or segments ?
I can confirm that scheduling only segments works, playback is perfectly fine.

A little context on how I cache information for audio sections..
In the code below, `file` is of type `AVAudioFile` loaded on disk from a `URL`, `begin` and `end` are `TimeInterval` values, and represent the start/end of my audio section.

```
let format = file.processingFormat

let startBufferFrameCount: AVAudioFrameCount = 4096
let endBufferFrameCount: AVAudioFrameCount = 4096

let audioSectionStartFrame = framePosition(at: begin, format: format)
let audioSectionEndFrame = framePosition(at: end, format: format)

let segmentStartFrame = audioSectionStartFrame + AVAudioFramePosition(startBufferFrameCount)
let segmentEndFrame = audioSectionEndFrame - AVAudioFramePosition(endBufferFrameCount)

startBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: startBufferFrameCount)
endBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: endBufferFrameCount)

file.framePosition = audioSectionStartFrame
try file.read(into: startBuffer)

file.framePosition = segmentEndFrame
try file.read(into: endBuffer)

middleSegment = (segmentStartFrame, AVAudioFrameCount(segmentEndFrame - segmentStartFrame))
frameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(audioSectionEndFrame - audioSectionStartFrame)
```

Also, the `framePosition(at:format:)` multiplies the `TimeInterval` value by the sample rate of the `AVAudioFormat` passed in.

I cache this information for every audio section, but I hear clicks at section boundaries, no matter if I schedule them in advance or not.
I also tried not mixing buffer and segments when scheduling, but I doesn't change anything, so I start thinking I'm doing wrong frame computations.